# Weights are not updated in Pytorch nn.Embedding

Tags: pytorch, word-embedding

I loaded the PyTorch's nn.Embedding module with a pre-trained embedding matrix. I set it to trainable as follows.

```
self.embedding_layer = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embed_size, paddding_idx=self.padding_idx)  
self.embedding_layer.weight = nn.Parameter(self.embedding)
self.embedding_layer.weight.requires_grad = True
```

I processed this output using Bidirectional Gated Recurrent Units network. 
After the model is trained, I checked whether the weights of nn.Embedding are updated. The weights were not updated. model.embedding_layer.weight and 'self.embedding' weights are the same. 
I checked the gradients of model.embedding_layer. They are all zeros.

Could you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add your code for training the model to the question?